# how to recovery lost imei no Samsung Galaxy s2 gt-i9100?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, imei

i have Samsung Galaxy s2 gt-i9100(unrooted)  and suddenly my network signal was missing.
and i dialed *#06# and display no imei no so how to solve that problem.

detail - 
gt-i9100
android version - 2.3.4
baseband - unknown
lernal version - 2.6.35.7-i9100xxkh3-cl479037
                  se.infra@sei-15 #2